# Jquery: load value from attr to class

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<button data-hover="bounce">test button</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('[data-hover="bounce"]').addClass('hvr-' + $(this).attr('data-hover'));
```

But this does not work. I get hvr-undefined. How do I get a hvr-bounce? Do I want to load the value from the data-hover attribute and create a class from this value, in this case hvr-bounce?

**I want to keep** `$('[data-hover="bounce"]')`

**SOLVED**

```
$('[data-hover="bounce"]').addClass(function() {
    return 'hvr-' + $(this).attr('data-hover');
}).attr('data-hover', '');
```

Comment: Since you're selecting a specific `data-hover=bounce` why not just `addClass('hvr-bounce')`?

Comment: Just my guess, but $(this) is likely not set in the context you are using it. Try storing the value in a variable first. `var class = $('[data-hover="bounce"]').attr('data-bounce');`. Then use that variable in your `addClass()` statement.

Comment: I have several effects and I would like to do it this way so I do not have to write or rewrite it in two places. That's why I ask if it can be done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `data-hover` is always `bounce`, so you can just use that instead of calling `.attr()`.

```
$('[data-hover="bounce"]').addClass('hvr-bounce');
```

If you want to generalize to all `data-hover` values, you can pass a function to `.addClass()`. Inside that function, `this` will be set to the current element being processed.

```
$('[data-hover']).addClass(function() {
    return 'hvr-' + $(this).attr('data-hover');
});
```